# Divide Union Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to divide the results from the two select statements and include a total?

Desired results 
[Required Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8fXN.png)

My current code

```
select sum(U.Orders) as sumtotal
from 
(
    select distinct count(p.PACKSLIP) as Orders
    from PICKHEAD as p
    where DATE_REQD = '2017-04-19'

    union 

    select distinct count(s.PACKSLIP) as Orders 
    from  SHIPHIST as s 
    where DATE_REQD = '2017-04-19' 
) AS U
```

Comment: How do you calculate the completion percentage?

Comment: No need to do `select distinct`, since those sub-queries returns only one row. Do UNION ALL instead, to keep both select's result if they are the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It would be a division based on the results from ship/sumtotal * 100

Answer (score 2):

Using a `CROSS JOIN` instead:

```
select pOrders + sOrders as sumtotal,
       (pOrders * 100) / (pOrders + sOrders)
from 
(
    select count(p.PACKSLIP) as pOrders
    from PICKHEAD
    where DATE_REQD = '2017-04-19'
) as p
cross join
(
    select count(s.PACKSLIP) as sOrders
    from  SHIPHIST
    where DATE_REQD = '2017-04-19' 
) as s
```

Comment: This is very close, it's the calculation of the percentage that's causing me the issues now. ideally it would be (sOrders/sumtotal)*100, but that obviously doesn't work

Comment: Can be done if you wrap this query up in a derived table.

Comment: I ended up doing this - cast((cast(Shipped AS decimal (10,5))/(Inprocess + Shipped)) * 100 AS decimal (10,2))

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want it

```
select sum(U.OrderList) + sum(U.Shiplist) as totalSalesOrder,sum(U.OrderList)/ (sum(U.Shiplist)+sum(U.OrderList)) * 100 as TotalComlpetionPercentage
from 
(
    select distinct count(p.PACKSLIP) as OrderList, 0 as ShipList
    from PICKHEAD as p
    where DATE_REQD = '2017-04-19'

    union 

    select distinct  0 as OrderList, count(s.PACKSLIP) as Shiplist
    from  SHIPHIST as s 
    where DATE_REQD = '2017-04-19' 
) AS U
```

Answer (score 0):

With only one result from each count, it can be done with a cross join:

```
select P.Orders + S.Orders as [Total Sales],  S.Orders * 100.0 / (P.Orders + S.Orders)  as [Total Completion Percentage]
from (
        select count(p.PACKSLIP) as Orders
        from PICKHEAD as p
        where DATE_REQD = '2017-04-19'
    ) as P
cross join (
        select count(s.PACKSLIP) as Orders 
        from  SHIPHIST as s 
        where DATE_REQD = '2017-04-19' 
    ) as S
```

Comment: Does SQL Server accept an INNER JOIN without an ON clause?

Comment: Yes. It is the same thing. Example: select * from
(select top 1 name from sysobjects) a
inner join
(select top 1 name from sysobjects) b on 1=1

select * from
(select top 1 name from sysobjects) a
cross join
(select top 1 name from sysobjects) b

Comment: Thanks for the info. (ANSI SQL requires an ON or USING clause.)

Comment: I've removed my INNER JOIN option for simplicity. I use INNER JOIN ON 1=1 sometimes because it fits well in my set of dynamic queries, but  CROSS JOIN looks better in a straight statement.